# Delete Non NA rows from a data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to use R to do some analysis for the job.

I have a data frame loaded from a TXT file.

```
  A  B  C  D
1 1  NA 3  NA
2 5  6  7  8
3 9  NA 11 NA
4 13 NA 15 NA
```

How can I take out the row 2 in the example?
I can take out row 1,3,4 by `na.omit(df)` now.

The expected output likes below.

```
  A  B  C  D
1 1  NA 3  NA
2 9  NA 11 NA
3 13 NA 15 NA
```

I need to keep the rows with NA inside.

Thanks

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "take out", please provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: `?complete.cases`

Comment: The duplicate question shows how to use `complete.cases` in order to keep rows that do not contain NA.  For this question you have to negate complete cases like this: `final[!complete.cases(final),]`, where "final" is your data frame.

Comment: final[!complete.cases(final),] works. Thanks a lot